# trying to print database in a web page but can't get a counter for table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to create a page that displays rpg ranks from a mysql database on a webpage

i went into the database and organized the data by level, so the person with the highest level is shown first and so on, however the database does not contain a table for ranks

I am trying to do that manually in dreamweaver but I don't know how, can I create a counter and have it display in the table?

I managed to get the following:
http://slayersgaming.com/rpgranks2.php

```
<?php
$dbh=mysql_connect("********", "**********", "*********") or die('Cannot connect to the database because: '. mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("C368969_thcrpgCSGO");

$rpgranks_sql = "SELECT * FROM `thc_rpg` ORDER BY `thc_rpg`.`level` DESC LIMIT 0, 30 ";

$rpgranks_query = mysql_query($rpgranks_sql) or die(mysql_error());

$rsrpgranks = mysql_fetch_assoc($rpgranks_query);


?>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>




<p>
<table width="501" height="58" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="240"><h2><strong>Name</strong></h2></td>
    <td width="70"><strong>Level</strong></td>
    <td width="70"><strong>XP</strong></td>
    <td width="70"><strong>Credits</strong></td>
    <td width="70"><strong>Rank</strong></td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <?php do{ ?>
<table width="501" height="58" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="240"><?php echo $rsrpgranks['name'];?></td>
    <td width="70"><?php echo $rsrpgranks['level'];?></td>
    <td width="70"><?php echo $rsrpgranks['xp'];?></td>
    <td width="70"><?php echo $rsrpgranks['credits'];?></td>
    <td width="70">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <?php } while ($rsrpgranks = mysql_fetch_assoc($rpgranks_query)) ?>


</p>
<p>&nbsp;       </p>
</body>
</html>
```

screen cap here: http://oi47.tinypic.com/21exdfs.jpg

Comment: first thing's first. Please remove your connection details from your post and show either blank strings or *s as someone could easily hack your stuff now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually really easy to do. You just need a counter in your do-while loop like this:

```
<?php
$counter = 1;
do{
?>
<table width="501" height="58" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $counter; ?></td>
    <td width="240"><?php echo $rsrpgranks['name'];?></td>
    <td width="70"><?php echo $rsrpgranks['level'];?></td>
    <td width="70"><?php echo $rsrpgranks['xp'];?></td>
    <td width="70"><?php echo $rsrpgranks['credits'];?></td>
    <td width="70">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php
    $counter++;
} while ($rsrpgranks = mysql_fetch_assoc($rpgranks_query))
?>
```